# List of graphics cards supported by Snow Leopard (10.6.x) but not OpenCL capable? (In older Intel Macs.)

Tags: snow-leopard, hardware, gpu, opencl

I want to know what graphics cards without OpenCL capabilities are supported by Mac OS 10.6 ‘Snow Leopard’? The list is probably really short.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Final Cut Pro X, Motion 5, Compressor 4: Graphics card compatibility](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4664) those cards are

- Intel Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) 950
- Intel Graphics Media Accelerator (GMA) X3100
- ATI Radeon X1300
- ATI Mobility Radeon X1600
- ATI Radeon X1600
- ATI Radeon X1900 XT
- ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT
- ATI Radeon HD 2600 PRO
- ATI Radeon HD 2600 XT
- ATI Radeon HD 3870
- NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT
- NVIDIA GeForce 7600 GT
- NVIDIA Quadro FX 4500